# Re-size logo on scroll down or up - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need some simple code example to re-size logo to some dimension like when scroll down put 30px by 30px and if scroll up or make refresh page will back to original size for example  60px by 60 with some effect like fade it.

Thanks

Comment: So where are you stuck???

Comment: @A.Wolff, liked your comment (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example, <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/b2rnY/)**</kbd>

```
<header>
  <img src="http://precision-software.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/jQuery.gif" class="logo">
</header>
```

---

```
header {
  background: violet;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
.logo {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

---

```
(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
       $('header').stop().animate({ height: '50px' }, 400, 'linear');
       $('.logo').stop().animate({ width: '30px', height: '30px' }, 400, 'linear');
    }
    else { 
       $('header').stop().animate({ height: '80px' }, 400, 'linear');
       $('.logo').stop().animate({ width: '60px', height: '60px' }, 400, 'linear');
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/rHmCu/164/)**</kbd>

You can do this by using a jquery lik

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10){  
   // x should be from where you want this to happen from top//
    //make CSS changes here

    $('.header').addClass("test");
      $('.logo').addClass("test");
  } 
  else{
    //back to default styles
    $('.header').removeClass("test");
      $('.logo').removeClass("test");
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<header class="header">
    <img class="logo" src="http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg" />
</header>
```

css

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.header {
   width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;

  -webkit-transition: linear .3s;
     -moz-transition: linear .3s;
      -ms-transition: linear .3s;
       -o-transition: linear .3s;
          transition: linear .3s;
}

.logo {
    height:60px;    
    width:auto;
    position: relative;

}

.test {
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
}
```